# How do I set ancestors in GAE datastore viewer?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

My use case involved 2 kinds, Customers and Orders.

From the docs I read that we can have descendants, the example shows persons as the kind. In my case I want a customer to have a bunch of orders underneath it. I want to try it out in the console before diving in but I can't seem to be able to set the customer as a key to the order. Any help?

[image]

This picture shows the Customer I have made. Note the id.

[image]

Here is the Order that I want as a descendant of the customer.
[image: Editing the order]

As you can see here I tried to put the customerID as a key, but the Ancestor path still points to the order itself.

Is this just a limitation of the console?

Also, if I try it in code, how can I refer to this specific datastore and namespace? I'm going to be doing this in java.

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
```

This looks like it's just making a new datastore.

Answer (score 2):

You can't set the ancestor of an existing entity. The ancestor is part of the ID, and must be set on creation; you can't change the ID once it's created.

There is only one datastore. That code just creates an instance of the client.

Comment: Ok Thanks for that. I tried with a new Entity and I couldn't get it to work. Maybe my syntax was wrong? How can I make a descendant with the GUI? And any advice on setting the namespace as "Main"?